# MapDB, serializers and compression

Tags: java, serialization, compression, mapdb, off-heap

I'm researching into off-heap cache and can't seem to find much information/benchmarks on memory consumption on-heap vs. off-heap (still in memory).

I'm planning to use [MapDB](http://mapdb.org). Documentation indicates that [compression can be applied](https://jankotek.gitbooks.io/mapdb/content/htreemap/) on serialized objects and/or entire data store.

Questions:

1. Does serialized object off-heap have smaller memory footprint in comparison to the same object on-heap? If possible ratio/benchmark?
2. What is overhead for `SerializerCompressionWrapper` (may be benchmark?)
3. How efficient is the compression?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) yes, the off-heap consumes less data compared to heap

2) there is no benchmark

3) it is very fast LZF compression, it should do about 1GB/s on reasonable CPU